# What does setting a workbook to ActiveSheet.Parent do?

Tags: vba, excel

What does setting a workbook to ActiveSheet.Parent do?

Comment: `Activesheet.parent == ThisWorkbook`

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192977%28v=office.15%29.aspx And also read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: It gives you the parent object of the `ActiveSheet` object which is the `WorkBook` object.

Answer (score 2):

It will set the object that of which is parent to the object you are calling.

So a good way to explain this is:

Workbook Worksheet   - The workbook is the parent and the worksheet is the child.

Worksheet Cell       - The worksheet is the parent and the cell is the child.